# jquery form specific dropdown values based on class

Tags: jquery, class, html-select

I know this is simple and the answer has got to be out there somewhere but I can't find it.

How do I select all the values of a series of dropdown menus with a specific class inside a specific form?  The specific form is important because I have dropdown menus with the same class outside the form that I do not wish to select.

```
<form action="http://link.com" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="addInfoForm" class="form_standard">

<select name="item_id[]" class="addItems">
<option value="0">---</option>
<option value="1">Value 1</option>
<option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>

<select name="item_id[]" class="addItems">
<option value="0">---</option>
<option value="1">Value 1</option>
<option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>

</form>

<select name="item_id[]" class="addItems">
<option value="0">---</option>
<option value="1">Value 1</option>
<option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

`$('#addInfoForm select.addItems option[selected="selected"]').each(function() { alert($(this).val()); });`

Comment: I'm still not getting any results.  This works but it selects everything and not just the value inside the form. $('.addItems').each(function() { alert($(this).val()); });

Comment: Actually going back through I think it's the way I'm generating the dropdowns.  I'm doing an append to a div inside of the form, duplicating the dropdown that is outside of the form.  I'll go back and see if there is another way to handle that.  Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#addInfoForm select.addItems")
```

Comment: So I ran this and I am not getting any results.   $("#addInfoForm select.addItems").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });

Comment: That's because this selector will only select the "select" tag. See chanaka77's answer for further guidance.